# list of /proc/fd/ path

Tags: linux, proc

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

When I execute `ls /proc/$$/fd` I got the following result

> 0  1  2  255

But when I execute `ls /proc/$$/fd/*` I got the following result

> ls: cannot access '/proc/126708/fd/3': No such file or directory
> /proc/126708/fd/0  /proc/126708/fd/1  /proc/126708/fd/2  /proc/126708/fd/255

But I don't why I got different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to realize is that wildcards are not expanded by 'ls' – they are expanded by the shell. This has two effects:

1. In your second example, the command line that 'ls' actually receives is a list of five exact names, already expanded at that point. (Variables such as $$ are also expanded.) So the exact command that's really being run is:

   ```
   ls /proc/126708/fd/0 /proc/126708/fd/1 /proc/126708/fd/2 /proc/126708/fd/3 /proc/126708/fd/255
   ```

   (You can see this using 'forkstat' or 'execsnoop' or possibly 'strace -f -e execve -p 126708'.)
2. When the shell is asked to expand a `*` wildcard, it needs to *open* the directory in order to list its contents – and that creates a file descriptor; specifically fd #3 in this case.

   Therefore the expanded list of the shell's file descriptors is self-referential and includes the same fd #3 that's being used to produce the list.

   Once the shell is done expanding wildcards, it closes the directory's fd again, causing 'fd/3' to disappear from the "live" /proc/126708 directory. However, the item does not disappear from the list of files that the wildcard expansion has just produced – once it's there, it's there, and it will be passed to 'ls'.

In short, the `/proc/126708/fd/3` entry appears during wildcard expansion, **because of** wildcard expansion, then disappears before the 'ls' command is run.

You can get a similar self-referential effect by doing `ls -l /proc/self/fd`, which will list the file descriptors held by 'ls' itself – you'll see that one of them correspond to the /proc/self/fd directory. (There's no error message in this case because the listing is done as a single step.)